# How to center a QProgressBar's chunk?

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget

I have this audio viewer that, for lack of a better widget, uses QProgressBars to display the overall volume and the volume of each RTA bin, in addition to selecting a range of "interesting" bins:

[image]

The parent widget has a stylesheet of `"background-color: DimGray;"`; I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem or not.  The progressbars themselves are set up like this:

```
AudioMeter::AudioMeter(..., QWidget* parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    meter = new QProgressBar(this);
    meter->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
    meter->setFormat("");
    meter->setGeometry(...);
    meter->setRange(FixedPoint::Zero, FixedPoint::One);
}
```

and used like this:

```
void AudioMeter::setValue(int value)
{
    meter->setValue(value);
}
```

The problem is that the chunks (in light blue) seem to be offset to the left by a few pixels and up by one or two, so it just doesn't look right.  This is true on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (pictured) and on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  How can I center them?

---

Or if there's a better widget to use (with straightforward code, not a custom thing with 20 re-implemented methods like I've seen in some examples), I'm open to that too.

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#the-box-model

[image: Qt Stylesheet Box Model]

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

It looks like the right padding is probably off for some reason.

```
// try this and see if it helps
meter->setStyleSheet("padding: 0;");
// or just zero out the right padding
meter->setStyleSheet("padding-right: 0;");
```

If not, you will probably need to do some iterations of stylesheet editing...

Use a `stylesheet.css` file in the same path as your program:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication

> `-stylesheet=` stylesheet, sets the application styleSheet. The value must be a path to a file that contains the Style Sheet.

So you run your program with

```
meters -stylesheet=./stylesheet.css
```

and fill in `stylesheet.css` with:

```
QProgressBar {
    /* attempt at fix by removing all padding */
    padding: 0;
    /* Another style to try out sometime:
QProgressBar {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: #05B8CC;
    width: 20px;
}*/
}
```

I've also done prototyping of stylesheets by connecting it's reload to an application wide hotkey or a pushbutton in your program.

```
QString stylesheet;
QFile f("stylesheet.css");
if (f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
{
    QTextStream in(&f);
    stylesheet = in.readAll();
}
qApp->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
qApp->style()->unpolish(qApp);
qApp->style()->polish(qApp);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, it was the `border` that did it, not the `padding`, but you were on the right track.  +1 and maybe an accept.